# Merging two data frames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two data frames below:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'date' : ['1', '2','3'],
     'value1' : ['a', 'b' ,'c'],
     'value2' : ['12','24','4']}
data2 = {'date' : ['2','3','4'],
     'value1' : ['b', 'c' ,'g'],
     'value2' : ['24','4','55']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1 = df1.set_index('date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
```

and here is my desired output:

```
desired_result = {'date' : ['1','2','3','4'],
     'value1' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g'],
     'value2' : ['12', '24', '4', '55']}
```

I have tried all different kinds of merge, join, concat but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly a merge problem but you can use `combine_first`:

```
df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()

  date value1 value2
0    1      a     12
1    2      b     24
2    3      c      4
3    4      g     55
```

---

Another suggestion is `concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index('date').drop_duplicates('date')

  date value1 value2
0    1      a     12
1    2      b     24
2    3      c      4
5    4      g     55
```

Answer (score 2):

Feel like a `groupby` problem

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0).last()
     value1 value2
date              
1         a     12
2         b     24
3         c      4
4         g     55
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a simple join/merge you will have some null values.

`pandas.DataFrame.combine_first` or `pandas.DataFrame.combine` are there for this purpose.

A simple: `df1.combine_first(df2)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely a perfect `merge` problem, simply use the `outer` merge and select the correct `keys` for the join like this.

Remove the `set_index` for the dataframes, you dont need that.

```
data1 = {'date' : ['1', '2','3'],
     'value1' : ['a', 'b' ,'c'],
     'value2' : ['12','24','4']}
data2 = {'date' : ['2','3','4'],
     'value1' : ['b', 'c' ,'g'],
     'value2' : ['24','4','55']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


# join with the key columns date, value1 & value2
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'value1', 'value2'], how='outer')
```

**Output**

```
    date    value1  value2
0   1       a       12
1   2       b       24
2   3       c       4
3   4       g       55
```